# Dismiss generated UITextfields

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I am generating `UITextfield`s dynamically on a scrollview as the user enters number in the    `UITextfield` (lets say it "A") and hits a button. But what i need to do is when user reenters   number in `UITextfield`s the previously displayed `UITextfield`s must be gone and new `UITextfield`s` must be generated.

```
for (UIView *field in self.scrollView.subviews)
{
     if([field isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
     [field removeFromSuperview];
}
```

eg- if first i generated 7 `UITextfield`s and afterwards i edit the "A" again and put 3 as value only 3 `UITextfield`s must  be visible. 
but in my code the 3 `UITextfield`s are overwritten on 7 but previous also displayed.

Comment: when you re-enter data in textfield you want to remove old data right?

Comment: yes and the previously generated textfeilds too..

Comment: How are you adding text fields ? Please post code if possible

Comment: Tell us what you need to do precisely. You are doing something in wrong manner, IMHO.

Comment: @jennis tis is how i am generating textfeilds  -      (void)dynamicTextfeildsPhone
{
    string = Points.text;
    Pointsvalue = [string intValue];
    txtFldFrame1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45,130,60,30)];
    for (x=1; x <= Pointsvalue ; x++)
    {
        txtFldFrame1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45,txtFldFrame1.frame.origin.y+34,60,30)];
        txtFldFrame1.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        txtFldFrame1.tag = x;
        txtFldFrame1.delegate=self;        
        [ScrollLag addSubview:txtFldFrame1];
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this code and this worked for me

```
for (y=1;y<=Pointsvalue;y++)
{
    UITextField *txtField =(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:y+Pointsvalue];
    if (txtField.tag == y+Pointsvalue)
    {
        [txtField removeFromSuperview];
        [Feilds2Array removeAllObjects];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But y did u regenrate new textfield if u can replace text in it and if u want animation then u can hide and unhide same textfield..

Comment: done this also but after unhiding the first textfeilds also displayed

Comment: so before unhiding change the text of textfield you want to display in new textfield

Comment: you can use tags to hide/unhide particular textfield

Answer (score 0):

Set the following code in your reloadTxtinput method. Call this method when user taps the button.

```
-(void)reloadTxtinput {

   for(UIView *subview in [scrollview subviews]) {
      if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
      } else {
             //Do nothing
      }
  }

}
```